# OAuth 2.0 Access Token Request using Google OAuth Playground

Tags: oauth, google-oauth, restful-authentication, oauth2-playground

I'm trying to exchange an OAuth 2.0 Authorization Code for an Access Token using Google's OAuth Playground tool. So, I get to step 2 and there it shows the HTTP POST request it will be sending out to MY_SERVER (I obfuscated the exact IP address for security reasons).

To me this looks correct and if I use a POST tool with exactly this request, it does arrive on my server. Launching it from the Playground, it doesn't arrive on my web server (nothing in the logs).

Does anybody have an idea what might be going wrong?

### THIS POST

POST /tb/html/token/ HTTP/1.1

Host: MY_SERVER.COM

Content-length: 170

content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

user-agent: google-oauth-playground

code=Splxl0576dGF6567gFG&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.google.com%2Foauthplayground&client_id=jarne&scope=&client_secret=some_secret&grant_type=authorization_code

### RESULTS IN

HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request

Content-length: 105

Content-type: text/plain

An error occured while connecting to the server: Unable to fetch URL: http://MY_SERVER.COM/tb/html/token/